# Count number of peaks when using pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
BytesReceived = df.iloc[:,0].values
print(type(BytesReceived)) #1d array
    
print(currentThreshold)
peaks = find_peaks(BytesReceived, height = currentThreshold)[0]
plt.plot(BytesReceived)  
plt.plot(peaks, BytesReceived[peaks],"X")
plt.show()
```

I am using **find_peaks** to find peaks in my graph (above code)

But after displaying peaks in graph, I also wanted to print output on the basis of presence of peak. Like, if peak is present do this and if not do this.

Initially, I was thinking, if I can count number of peaks and put the condition on that basis.

I will be grateful, if anyone can help regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not 100% clear to me what you are aiming at. I assume, you would like to add a marker X at all positions that are above a given threshold.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

BytesReceiver = pd.DataFrame( random.sample(range(0, 100), 50), columns=['Data'])
threshold = 70

peaks = BytesReceiver[BytesReceiver.Data > threshold]

plt.plot(BytesReceiver)
plt.scatter(peaks.index, peaks.Data, c='r', marker='X') #marker: red cross
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Count the peaks**

There are several options, for instance: Check the existence of any peak and do something.

```
if (peaks.any(axis=None)):
    print("Has peaks")
else:
    print("Has no peaks")
```

Use the amount of peaks to do something.

```
if (len(peaks) > 0):
    print("Has peaks")
else:
    print("Has no peaks")
```

Comment: Apparently, I was able to add marker. But my question was, is there any way to calculate these marker / peaks

Comment: ok, I updated the post accordingly